# "Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed" when calling function on deployed contract 0xf75056aedfeef65ca4889c2f053bfd3158c131f2 (ROPSTEN)

Tags: solidity

"Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed" when calling function on deployed contract https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf75056aedfeef65ca4889c2f053bfd3158c131f2 (ROPSTEN)

I have verified the contract code here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf75056aedfeef65ca4889c2f053bfd3158c131f2#code

This is the error I get when I try to withdraw 100000000000000000 wei

[image]

I am using MetaMask to access web3.. hmmm...

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute the function on Remix. For some reason Remix requires large integers to be provided as strings. In the textbox next to the `withdrawFunds` function button you should enter "100000000000000000" **(between quotes)** instead of 100000000000000000.

Comment: The reason is JavaScript.